# is there a way to start a for loop again if your condition != null in java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

As the title.. is this possible?
For example:

```
for(blah blah blah){
code omitted
}
if(variable != null){
go back to start of for;
}
```

Comment: Yes, put the for loop in a separate method and call that method before and from inside the `if`

Comment: Can you show us your "blah blah blah" condition for your for loop? Perhaps your loop logic wants changing. Or, alternatively, move the loop into a method and call it.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use a loop:

```
while (variable != null) {
    for(blah blah blah){
        code omitted
    }
}
```

That's the preferred control structure for repeating something while a condition exists.  In this case the condition is `variable != null`.

Comment: You do need to set `variable` to a non-`null` value to start with, though. (Slightly odd that they want to continue while the variable **isn't** `null`, but it does come up sometimes.) That or, if the value can only be determined within the loop, use `do-while` instead.